# Unable to set Network in RHEL 6.4

Tags: linux, networking, rhel6

I am not able to get ip in RHEL machine, It only works when i run command

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

I am new to RHEL i am not able to get this. I have tried below command to come to this above solution, But i want it automatic.

```
# ethtool eth0
```

or

```
# mii-tool eth0
```

I used above command from stack overflow answers to find which link is actually up and i found it is `eth0`

but on my machine below are there

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
```

Contains entry for `DEVICE=eth1`

i manually changed all these to file `eth0` and `DEVICE=eth0`

Still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way out of this

i run command `sudo dhclient eth0` then i got network to make it permanent i used `ifconfig` for getting mac address for it and then updated mac address in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and its done